# Compare the file names in two directories

Tags: linux, bash

I have to create a bash script that compares content by file names in two directories, for example "First_Directory" contains file with name ***"123456"*** therefore "Second_Directory" should also contain ***"_file_123456.png"***. 
If the "Second_Directory" doesn't contain exact number in the file name from the "First_Directory", then copy a "dummy.png" file from the "Third_Directory" to the "Second_Directory" and rename it according to example: ***"_file_[First_Directory_File_Name].png"***

Path: 
*/path/to/directory/First_Directory/Second_Directory/* 
*/home/username/Third_Directory/dummy.png*

First_Directory content:
123456
789012
345678

Second_Directory content:
_file_123456.png
_file_789012.png
_file_345678.png

```
DIR1=/path/to/directory/First_Directory/
DIR2=/path/to/directory/First_Directory/Second_Directory/
PNG=/home/username/Third_Directory/dummy.png

DIFF=$(diff <(find $DIR1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" -printf '%f\n') <(find $DIR2 -type f -name '_file_*.png' -printf '%f\n'))

if [ "$DIFF" ];
then
   cp $PNG $DIR2
fi
```

My script only displays difference between these two directories. I couldn't find a solution on how to compare only specific part of the file name. It also should copy and rename a file in the "Second_Directory" as I mentioned in the description.

Comment: What should happen if a file exists in the Second_Directory without its corresponding file in the First_Directory?

Comment: @choroba Hello, it shouldn't check this condition since in my case there might be missing corresponding file only in the First_directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping over the first directory would be the proper solution here. For your updated requirement, you can find the base directories first and loop them.

```
for DIR1 in `find . -name First_Directory_*`
do
   DIR2="$DIR1"/Second_Directory
   PNG=/path/to/dummy.png
   for file in "$DIR1"/*
   do
     if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        dir2_file="$DIR2"/_file_${file##*/}.png
        if [ ! -f "$dir2_file" ]; then
           cp "$PNG" "$dir2_file"
        fi
     fi
   done
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but I have one more question. Let's say I have path to directory like this: "/path/to/directory/Project_1/Test_1/First_Directory/Second_Directory/". In my case "/path/to/directory/" and "/Second_Directory/" will always be constant, but the name for these three directories: "/Project_1/Test_1/First_Directory/" will differ since in my case there are many projects. Is it possible to check "First_Directory" even though it will have different names?

Comment: I can't quite get what you mean. You do assign DIR1 and DIR2 right? Do you have various pairs of directories you want to apply the same operation to? A sample use case would help to elaborate more.

Comment: Directory structure example: [Link to the image](https://ibb.co/sw5fTFF).

"/path/to/directory/" will always stay the same, but the next three directory names will be completely random, except for the "Second_Directory". The idea is to go three levels deep (starting from "/path/to/directory/") into each of these directories and execute the script.

Comment: If I use for loop that calls your file check function, is this will be proper solution?

    `function()
    {
    ...
    }

    for dir in /path/to/directory/*/*/*;
    do
       (cd "$dir" && function);
    done`

Comment: I don't think you can approach it that way. You need an exact list of folders and you need to iterate through those folders and call the function.

Comment: If you are sure that the name is going to start with First_Directory_*, you can use that to get a list of directories to loop.

Comment: Check the updated answer. That is a rough solution for your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I will mark this as answer and going to figure out most suitable option for my situation based on provided solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the files in the first directory by a for loop:

```
#! /bin/bash
dir1=...
dir2=...
dummy=...    

for file in "$dir1"/* ; do
    target=$dir2/_file_${file##*/}.png
    [[ -f $target ]] || cp "$dummy" "$target"
done
```

Don't use uppercase variable names for non-system variables to prevent clashes.

Comment: Yes, the source files are in _First_Directory_, but without prefix or suffix. Not sure `*.png` is going to match anything useful.